# SQL Server doesn't get its naming right

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, instance

When I installed a new instance of SQL Server, I specifically named it `MSSQLSERVER01`. Indeed, after everything was completed, the following folder had been created.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER01
```

However, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio was unable to connect to `DESKTOP-MHK0JT6\MSSQLSERVER01`. I am able to connect to `DESKTOP-MHK0JT6` and `DESKTOP-MHK0JT6\`, but that's not what I want.

When trying to connect to `MSSQLSERVER01` from `R` using `odbc::dbConnect`, it says that the server either doesn't exist or that access was denied.

Why is this happening? Surely the server exists, because otherwise, the folder would not have been created. (The folder is not empty, by the way, it contains the non-empty folder `MSSQL` and `R_SERVICES`.)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The following lines, among others, are found in the log.

```
The service account is 'NT Service\MSSQLSERVER'.
Server name is 'DESKTOP-MHK0JT6'.
Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv6> 1433].
Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\SQLLocal\MSSQLSERVER ].
Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\sql\query ].
Server is listening on [ ::1 <ipv6> 1434].
Server is listening on [ 127.0.0.1 <ipv4> 1434].
The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/DESKTOP-MHK0JT6 ] for the SQL Server service.
The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/DESKTOP-MHK0JT6:1433 ] for the SQL Server service.
```

Comment: So look at the file `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER01\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG` and it will tell you what IP addresses, ports and named pipes the instance is listening on.

Answer (score 1):

You should open MMC (SQL Configuration Manager), in there you can see SQL Server Services and the names of configured instances too.

[image]

Comment: `Host name` is `DESKTOP-MHK0JT6` and  `name` is `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)`. Logging in with `DESKTOP-MHK0JT6\MSSQLSERVER` does not work either. Still not understanding why the name does not have the "01" in it, in contrast to the folder name `C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER01`.